# Rounding number to nearest interval

Tags: php

So i have a predefined interval, can be 5, 10, 15, etc

If someone inputs 20 i need it to round up based on the interval. So if it was a 15 minute interval, it would automatically go to 30, if it was a 45 minute interval, it would go to 45

Basically anything <= interval becomes interval
anything inbetween intervals becomes the next highest interval

I dont want to write some convoluted php function to do this when there may be a simple way i am just not aware of.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rounding up would be:

```
$ceiled = $interval * ceil( $value / $interval);
```

Comment: What if the interval is a decimal?

Comment: @ari: that still works.   `ceil(3.3 / 1.6) * 1.6 = 3 * 1.6 =  4.8`

Answer (score 2):

```
roundedInput  = (Ceiling( Input / Interval)) * Interval
```

So, given an input of 20 and an interval of 15, you'd get:

20/15 = 1.33

1.33 rounded up = 2

2 * 15 = 30

Answer (score 2):

$Rounded = Ceil($value /  $interval) * $interval;